# Ionic/Angularjs: pass data back from detail to master

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In Ionic (but in general in angularjs) i have a Master/Detail pages:
in the Detail page i select some data and i want pass this data back to the Master controller.

How can i achieve it in angularjs?

Answer (score 2):

use factories / services for sharing data between controllers

example:

*myCtl.js*

```
angular

    .module('app')
    .controller('myCtl', myCtl);

function myCtl(sharedDataFactory) {

   var vm = this;

   vm.someValue = sharedDataFactory.getMySharedValue();
   vm.setSomeValue = sharedDataFactory.setMySharedValue;

}
```

any controller in your app may use sharedDataFactory, where you have your shared value and get/set methods

you may get the idea

hope this helps